# How can I add standard users to the print managers group?

Tags: terminal, permission, printing, network

I'm sysadmin for a small company; my users are on 10.6.8 (iMacs) and do not have admin rights for various reasons.  The only times this is annoying is when a print job jams or otherwise does not go through, and the user can handle the issue, but I have to come by and type admin credentials to "Resume" the printer.

Is there an easy enough way to grant standard users rights to the Print Managers/Admin group?

Answer (score 2):

You can grant users partial admin rights (printers only) by making them members of the _lpadmin group.  This is a hidden system group, so it doesn't appear in the Accounts preference pane; you have to grant membership from the command line (as a real admin).  You can do this for an individual user:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a fred _lpadmin
```

or just add everyone:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -t group -a everyone _lpadmin
```

BTW, membership in _lpadmin grants both the ability to manage queues, and also configure printer settings; if you just want to grant queue management (e.g. resuming queues), I believe you can do that by adding people to _lpoperator instead.

Answer (score 0):

For 10.5.8 there was [solution](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081107092520601) involving Terminal.
Try it and tell us if it will work.